# Why is my linked list output variable not being updated each loop iteration?

Tags: python, class, linked-list

I wrote this code to add two numbers stored as linked lists for a problem on Leetcode. I am getting an output that indicates my variable is not being updated in the while loop, but I don't understand why. What am I missing?

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
#class ListNode:
#    def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        carrybit = 0
        output = ListNode(0)
        iteration = 0
        while l1.next != None or l2.next != None:
            temp = ListNode((l1.val + l2.val + carrybit)%10)
            if l1.val + l2.val + carrybit > 9:
                carrybit = 1
            else:
                carrybit = 0

            temp2 = output.next
            while temp2 != None:
                temp2 = temp2.next
            temp2 = temp


            l1 = l1.next
            l2 = l2.next

        return output
```

Comment: You don't need a class for this. `addTwoNumbers` doesn't use its `self` argument at all; it can simply be a regular function instead of a method of a class.

Comment: The class is just the framework given by the leetcode site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has absolutely no effect:

```
        temp2 = output.next
        while temp2 != None:
            temp2 = temp2.next
        temp2 = temp
```

The value of `temp2` is updated until it reaches `None` and then it is replace by `temp`.  After that `temp2` is never used and neither is `temp`.  They are both reassigned with new values that do not depend on the result of this operation.

Since `temp` is assigned a new `ListNode` that isn't linked to anything and is never changed, the `ListNode` will go out of scope and disappear.

The only other thing happening there is assignment of the `carrybit` which is only used in a `ListNode` that will be trashed.

The whole while loop ends up doing nothing at all.

I would suggest a somewhat less convoluted approach:

```
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    output   = None
    lastNode = None
    carry    = 0
    while not (l1 is None and l2 is None):
        if l1 : carry,l1 = l1.val+carry,l1.next
        if l2 : carry,l2 = l2.val+carry,l2.next
        nextNode = ListNode(carry%10)
        carry = carry // 10
        if output: lastNode.next = nextNode
        else     : output        = nextNode
        lastNode = nextNode
    if carry: 
        lastNode.next = ListNode(carry%10)
    return output
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I get an error testing your implementation. Specifically I get "Type error: __init__() takes two positional arguments but three were given"

Comment: Oh, ok that makes sense. But for the given problem we can't modify the ListNode class. So with the given class initializer, do you know the best way to access the last node in the list and modify it accordingly?

Comment: OK, changed it to use the ListNode class as is.

Comment: BTW i'm assuming the start of the chains contains the least significant digit right ? Otherwise the logic will have to be reversed.

Comment: Yes, correct it is supposed to start with least significant digit

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values to the local `temp2` variable. Doing that will only change `temp2`, `output.next` or the previous `temp2.next` will not be modified.

You need to actually assign to `output.next` if you want to change it.

Comment: Ok but if I don't know the depth of the linked list, how do I access the last node and update it appropriately?